# Write data to kudu through pyspark

Tags: pyspark, kudu

I'm using Spark version 2.11 and Apache Kudu version 1.10.
I am trying to configure pyspark streaming to write to Apache Kudu But the write speed is always too slow, about 10000item/s.
See attached screen shot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jekyU.png

I have the following configuration `memory_limit_hard_bytes=5G` and `block_cache_capacity_mb=2G` I think that is enough.

I have this configuration and i need to know how to modify it?

```
df.writeStream \
        .format("org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu") \
        .option('kudu.master', base.KUDU_MASTER)\
        .option('kudu.table',"test_table") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/hive/spark_offset/kudu_test") \
        .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds') \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .start()
```

Comment: it has to build columnar structures, that takes some time

Comment: only 1 task I note

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815419/apache-kudu-slow-insert-high-queuing-time  may offer some additional insights

Comment: http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2240994/Intro%20to%20Apache%20Kudu%20(Belgium%20CUG%20Oct%202016).pdf?t=1478514524776